# Error code 100 while writing a code for Facebook API

Tags: facebook

I get this error:

> API Error Code: 100 API Error Description: Invalid parameter Error
>   Message: next is not owned by the application.

in this index.php file:

```
<
?php
$appapikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$appsecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

require_once 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook ($appapikey, $appsecret);

$user = $facebook->require_login();

echo $user;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the developers section, under your website, go to:

Settings > Web Site >

Site URL: http://example.com
Site Domain: example.com

This error can occur if your domain is listed as http://example.com but you are coming from http://www.example.com. The Site Domain ensures that the subdomain `www` gets recognized properly.

Comment: What if you're testing with `http://localhost:8000/` for app URL? I tried a domain of `localhost`, still got an error.

Comment: You should ensure that at your facebook's app website url with trailing slash and redirect_uri is also with trailing slash. This fixed my problem with `localhost`

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't directly address your question, might I suggest you use the latest version of the Facebook PHP library, available here:

http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/

It doesn't have the `require_login` method but is lightweight and can handle any API call.

Comment: Yeah.. but i m quite used to use fbml so it will be a l'll difficult for me to get used to this api

Comment: Is there no way out to do this in fbml.